# javascript error handling

Tags: asp.net, javascript, event-handling

I have a javascript function for checking errors which I am calling on OnClicentClick event of a button. Once it catch a error I want to stop execution of the click event. But in my case it always it always executes the onclick event.

Following is my function:

```
function DisplayError() {

        if (document.getElementById('<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>').value.length < 6 || document.getElementById('<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>').value.length > 12) {
            document.getElementById('<%=lblError.ClientID %>').innerText = "Password length must be between 6 to 12 characters";
            return false;
        }
        var str = <%=PhoneNumber()%>;
        if(str.length <10)
        {
            alert('<%=phoneNum%>'.length);
            document.getElementById('<%=lblError.ClientID %>').innerText = "Phone Number not in correct format";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

button html code:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" ValidationGroup="submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="DisplayError()"/>
```

It should not execute the button click event once it satisfies any of the IF condition in the javascript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OnClientClick="if (!DisplayError()) return false;"

That way, if no error occurred, it will still postback, but only when an error occurs, it will return false, and cancel the postback.

Comment: hi brian,
  i tried your code, but it is still not working for me. Can u please check my javascript function, am i making a mistake there??

Comment: thanks brian ur code finally worked for me. Had to do some debugging but i got my error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnClientClick="return DisplayError();"`

Comment: hi,
  i tried your code but it is still not working  
  plz check i am also having a onclick event in button click

Comment: i want to fire onclick event when the OnClientClick does not return any error but not when it gives me a error